# What would getting hit by a micro black hole laser look like?

Tags: science-based, stars, black-holes, simulated-worlds, relativity

So your star and/or planet gets hit by the [CrushSun](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36326/how-much-energy-does-this-sun-crushing-ship-the-crushsun-use). The huge laser looks terrifying, but then you realize that the main weapon is the microblack hole it hit you with.

What does it look like when a star gets sucked up by a micro-black hole? What about a planet?

(Keep in mind that a microblack hole and a regular sized black hole will absorb things differently. A microblack hole will likely fall to the core of a sun before absorbing it, I think.)

Comment: This has no evidence behind it which is why I am using a comment. I would agree with the fall into the core bit. I think that from the surface of a nearby plante the star would then appear to slowly dim slightly and shrink slowly. I think the timescale would make it hard to see any difference over say a minute but  after a long time there would be a noticab shrinkage and dimming. A little like a clocks hour hand. You can't see it moving but come back  after an hour and it has moved an obvious distance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [expected observable effects of a micro black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole#Expected_observable_effects) as reported by Wikipedia:

> It is unlikely that a collision between a microscopic black hole and an object such as a star or a planet would be noticeable. The small radius and high density of the black hole would allow it to pass straight through any object consisting of normal atoms, interacting with only few of its atoms while doing so. It has, however, been suggested that a small black hole (of sufficient mass) passing through the Earth would produce a detectable acoustic or seismic signal.

According to that depiction, you have your damaging elements reversed. The laser does the damage and the micro black hole is just a stage show.

As to whether the micro black hole would consume or even meaningfully impact the star, the answer is no, [as answered by Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190308).

Comment: Wouldn't the black hole stop at the core though? and then suck it in from the inside.

Comment: @Sam That has an answer on Physics SE. I've linked it into my answer.

Comment: Black holes don't "suck". Things can fall in, like any other mass.

Answer (score 1):

What it "looks" like is interesting. A black hole is invisible by definition, since the escape velocity is greater than the speed of light. The black hole will become visible through two mechanisms:

The "Einstein ring". The powerful gravitational field of a black hole bends light coming near the event horizon, so anyone looking in the direction of a black hole will see a strange "ring" of distortion as the light from distant stars (or the Sun, depending on your relative position) passes around the volume black hole occupies. You might see something like this:

[image]

Or this

[image]

This is actually going to be very difficult to see in the scenario, since the black hole being created is of such a small diameter that the Einstein ring will also be similarly microscopic in size. If you are seeing an Einstein ring the size of the illustrations you are probably far too close to the black hole already

The other thing which makes black holes visible is the accretion disk of in falling matter. In this case you won't see anything because the micro black hole will be starting in relatively clean space without much matter to ingest until it hits the solar atmosphere. The tiny size of the black hole will also limit the actual amount of matter being ingested, so any accretion disc forming as it passes through the solar photosphere will be much too small to notice.

Now the question [Is there a way to create a bomb to destroy a star?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-bomb-to-destroy-a-star/36121#36121) suggests that there might be another effect. If the in falling black hole can create enough energy deposited in a small volume of the star, it might trigger a chain reaction of fusion in the outer layers of the Sun, creating what is in effect, an artificial type 1 nova.

If that is the case, you will see the CrushSun fire the weapon, followed shortly afterwards by a blinding flare as the star is induced to go nova. After that excitement dies down, the remains of the star will settle for a very long time until the black hole in the centre grows enough to start consuming mass at an appreciable rate (probably centuries). The extra gravitational pull in the centre will cause the star to continue to brighten as heavier elements are pulled towards the core and reach conditions that induce fusion, as well as the energy of the accretion disc forming in the centre of the star itself. The eventual demise of the star will probably be announced as the accretion disc pokes through the surface of the star and stellar material is rapidly flung into space.

Answer (score -1):

If the Earth were hit by a micro-black hole I would think that it would look a lot like a total eclipse, for the first 20 minutes. This is how long the black hole would take to suck in the earths atmosphere and satellites.
 After that we would all suffocate before we noticed anything else !
As the black hole sucks in material it will expand, and as it expands it will become stronger. During a black holes feeding period it emits x-rays, this radiation would make us all very sick and probably bring us to out knees before we suffocate. 
 When the black hole starts sucking in material from the earth it will do so in a pattern reminiscent of a balloon loosing air.

You imagine a balloon all filled up with air, now imagine that there is something in the center of the balloon, as the air is let out the balloon collapses inward.

A Black hole sucking in material from the earth would distort the earths surface and make it look like this, for a few minutes till everything was gone.

As for your micro-black hole laser weapon ?
I think we may be able to answer this with Pi, it would look like an infinitely collapsing sphere were V= 4 thirds pi * Pi/R. 
Not to shabby.

This is essentially like firing your weapon at another Multiverse, the entire multiverse would take forever to collapse, not to mention the size of all its separate universes.
(and we all know how big out universe is)

Comment: Welcome to the site, Neo One. Since this is a science-based question, could you provide links to indicate where you're getting this information? (They don't need to be peer-reviewed papers.) Your info contradicts the info I uncovered, so I would like to know. Also, black holes don't suck.

Comment: As said in other posts: A micro-black hole would just pass trough the earth without any noticable damage. The Large Hadron Collider and the fear it instilled in people caused scientists to post about micro-black holes to remove their fear. http://press.web.cern.ch/backgrounders/safety-lhc